# iOS 5 tel link not working

Tags: ios, tel

I built an app that has a simple `tel` link:

```
- (IBAction) makeCall:(id)sender
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8005555555"]];
}
```

It worked fine when I was testing on iOS 4.

Just before I released it, I upgraded to iOS 5, and now I find that the tel link isn't working. Does anyone know if this might be something to do with iOS 5, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

UPDATE: This is for an app I built for the company I work for, and in order to fix it, my boss has to give me access to the code, which he's kind of dragging his feet with. I'll update as soon as I have access and can find out if the solution ott gave works.

Comment: I can't see a reason why the code above wouldn't work. Are you certain that your action is being messaged?

Comment: @Brian, I tested it before release, and had no problems, and never changed the code. I'm not at my Mac right now, so I can't review the code, but I just received word that it's not working and personally verified it on two iPhones. In summary, I'm like 99.9999999998% positive that the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct URL should be `tel:8005555555`. It could be that the `//` were ignored earlier.

See also http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: But is this new to iOS 5? I had no problems with it before upgrading, and have found many samples here on SO that use `//`.

Comment: Also, if following your link explicitly, it would seem that you should use 1-800-555-5555, but this also seems like it wouldn't be required.

Comment: There are 4 "visual separators" you can use for better readability, the are `- . ( )`.

Comment: Yes, but the point being that `//` used to work, and should still work unless something changed in iOS 5.

Comment: As I said, the `//` may have been silently ignored in the past.

Comment: Ahh, hadn't caught that from your original answer. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I know that this is an older answer, but Google ranks it quite high. Just wanted to add that SPACES in the phone number will also cause a tel: url to not work.