# Make a phone call with objective-c not working IOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I've tried with the code below:

```
NSString *phoneStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"tel://%@",[[dCliente objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:phoneStr];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url ];
[phoneStr release];
[url release];
```

Can somebody tell me What could be the problem?
I tested directly in iPhone with IOS6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, the problem was a space between tel:// and phone number.
I did this:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
NSString *phoneStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"tel:%@",[[dCliente objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `//` between `tel:` and the number. See [iOS 5 tel link not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233509/ios-5-tel-link-not-working).